# How to get all images from a webpage in all cases?

Tags: php

I am using this script to get all images from a generic external webpage:

```
$url = ANY URL HERE;
$html = @file_get_contents($url,false,$context);
$dom = new domDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach ($images as $image) {
 echo $image->getAttribute('src');
}
```

But in some cases like this ( where the image is in "**rel:image_src**" )

```
<img src="http://example.com/example.png" rel:image_src="http://example.com/dir/me.jpg"  />
```

it doesn't work.

How can I do ?

Comment: `$image->getAttribute('rel:image_src')` ?

Comment: the problem is that sometimes is rel:image_src, sometimes is rel:ax_image_src, sometime si rel:img_src, etc. So there is not the same attribute. So in this way it will not work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the node has an attribute `rel:image_src`

```
foreach ($images as $image) {
  if( $image->hasAttribute('rel:image_src') ) {
     echo $image->getAttribute('rel:image_src');
  } else {
     echo $image->getAttribute('src');
  }
}
```

Comment: the problem is that sometimes is rel:image_src, sometimes is rel:ax_image_src, sometime si rel:img_src, etc. So there is not the same attribute. So in this way it will not work :(

Comment: ok, then how do you know that you have to ignore the image in `src` tag and consider the one in `re:xxxxx` tags? Is there any logic behind that? If so, that would help in making the decision via code...

Comment: Uhm, there is no logic behind that.Maybe in my opinion the only way is to retrieve ALL .jpg, .gif or .png files from the html page.

Comment: In that case, what you can do is get all attributes of all image tags and all their values. Now check their values if they end in `jpg`, `png`, `gif` etc. That way, you can can find out if the image is present in an attribute other than `src`. It won't be a pretty looking code, but will work most of the time with manual interventions :). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

you could include both:

```
foreach ($images as $image) {
  echo $image->getAttribute('src');
  echo $image->getAttribute('rel:image_src');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `rel:image_src` to take precidence, check for the attribute's presence and use it selectively:

```
$url  = ANY URL HERE;
$html = @file_get_contents($url,false,$context);
$dom  = new domDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach ($images as $image) {
  if ($image->hasAttribute('rel:image_src')
  {
    echo $image->getAttribute('rel:image_src');
  }
  else
  {
    echo $image->getAttribute('src');
  }

}
```

Comment: the problem is that sometimes is rel:image_src, sometimes is rel:ax_image_src, sometime si rel:img_src, etc. So there is not the same attribute. So in this way it will not work :(